# Inserting a new indicator column to tell if a given row maximizes another column in SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have a table in SQL that looks like this

```
PRODUCT_ID_1 PRODUCT_ID_2 SCORE
1            2            10
1            3            100
1            10           3000
2            10           10
3            35           100
3            2            1001
```

That is, PRODUCT_ID_1,PRODUCT_ID_2 is a primary key for this table.

What I would like to do is use this table to add in a row to tell whether or not the current row is the one that maximizes SCORE for a value of PRODUCT_ID_1.

In other words, what I would like to get is the following table:

```
PRODUCT_ID_1 PRODUCT_ID_2 SCORE  IS_MAX_SCORE_FOR_ID_1
1            2            10               0
1            3            100              0 
1            10           3000             1
2            10           10               1 
3            35           100              0
3            2            1001             1
```

I am wondering how I can compute the IS_MAX_SCORE_FOR_ID_1 column and insert it into the table without having to create a new table.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Sorry - I was wondering how to do this... Ideally without having to create a new table

Comment: Do you mean to alter the table to add a column? Or, how to set or to maintain the values in this new column?

Comment: Both - I would like to compute these values, then insert them as a new column onto the existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this...

```
Select PRODUCT_ID_1, PRODUCT_ID_2 ,SCORE,
(Case when b.Score=
(Select Max(a.Score) from TableName a where  a.PRODUCT_ID_1=b. PRODUCT_ID_1) 
then 1 else 0 End) as IS_MAX_SCORE_FOR_ID_1 
 from TableName b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function for this:

```
select product_id_1,
       product_id_2, 
       score, 
       case 
         when score = max(score) over (partition by product_id_1) then 1
         else 0
       end as is_max_score_for_id_1
from the_table
order by product_id_1;
```

(The above is ANSI SQL and should run on any modern DBMS)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add this column to my existing table?

Comment: You can always alter table first and then run a update with which has that case statement in it.

Comment: @BerkU. it's bad practise to store values that can be derived from the existing data

Comment: To some extent I agree but I would say it depends upon the need and response time required. It might be little performance hit to do the calculation every time you need the values. it also depends upon the size of table. And just FYI above code will not work in mysql since it does not have support for partition by analytical function.